# How can I filter with a LIST <T> in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to make a change to my query in LINQ but I don't know how to do it.

The following expression works, but now I have to add a list to it that will be dynamic.

```
var result = (from t1 in table.Where(t => t.namepAdm == "ZZ-013" || t.namepAdm == "ZZ-030" || t.namepAdm == "ZZ-033") 
              join t2 in provtel on t1.provTel  equals t2.provTel             
              orderby t1.namepAdm                             
              select new xyEntity
              {
                 //TODO
              }).ToList();
```

To the following program I want to add a list that fills up before the "GetNameTable" is called.

```
private void GetNameTable(List<nUEntity> npA)
{
    var listNPA = npA.Select(x=>x.npAdm);   
    
    var result = (from t1 in table.Where(t => t.namepAdm == **** listNPA **** )
    join t2 in provtel on t1.provTel  equals t2.provTel               
    orderby t1.namepAdm                           
    select new xyEntity
    {
        //TODO
    }).ToList();
}

void Main()
{
    var username = new List<nUEntity>();
    username.Add(new nUEntity { username = "user1", npAdm = "ZZ-013" });
    username.Add(new nUEntity { username = "user1", npAdm = "ZZ-030" });
    username.Add(new nUEntity { username = "user1", npAdm = "ZZ-033" });

    GetNameTable(username);
}

private class nUEntity
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string npAdm { get; set; }
}
```

How can I add the list to be able to compare each of the elements.

```
var result = (from t1 in table.Where(t => t.namepAdm == **** listNPA **** )
```

In the same way that I do it here:

```
var result = (from t1 in table.Where(t => t.namepAdm == "ZZ-013" || t.namepAdm == "ZZ-030" || t.namepAdm == "ZZ-033")
```

Comment: `.Where(t => listNPA.Contains(t.namepAdm))`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH........ Works 100% :)